# How to reference sys.stdout created outside of a DAG to be used inside of a DAG with withParam?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argoproj

I am working with an Argo workflow.

There is a DAG step in my `entrypoint` which follows several normal steps. One of these steps does a `sys.stdout`. Once inside of the DAG step, I want some of the tasks to reference the results from the `sys.stdout`.

I know if we wanted to reference the `sys.stdout` when the workflow just goes from one step to the next (without the DAG), we can do `{{steps.step-name.outputs.result}}`. The same does not work inside of a DAG task though.

How can I reference the sys.stdout inside of a DAG task so I can use it with `withParam`?

**Edit:**

The workflow looks like the following:

```
  templates:
  - name: the-entrypoint
    steps:
    - - name: step01
        template: first-step
    - - name: step02
        template: second-step
    - - name: step03
        template: third-step
    - - name: step04-the-dag-step
        template: fourth-step
```

In general, if `third-step` does a `sys.stdout`, we can reference it by `{{steps.step03.outputs.result}}` in `fourth-step`. However, in this case `fourth-step` is a DAG, and if one of the DAG tasks wants to use the `sys.stdout`, calling `{{steps.step03.outputs.result}}` as an argument/parameter inside of DAG tasks throws up an error.

The question is then how can one correctly reference the `sys.stdout` generated by `third-step` inside `fourth-step` DAG tasks?

Comment: Can you paste an example workflow? I’m not sure what you mean by a DAG step in your entrypoint that follows several normal steps. My understanding is that a template may have either a DAG or a set of steps, but not both.

Comment: It turns out that one (or maybe more) of the steps can be a DAG. I ended up getting around the issue by making the `sys.stdout` as an argument to the DAG step, and then make use of that argument in various DAG tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A bit of background about template outputs

Argo Workflows supports a number of different [*types of templates*](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/workflow-concepts.md#template-types).

Each type of template supports different types of reference *within the template*.

**Within a `steps` template**, you may access the output parameters of other steps with `steps.step-name.outputs.parameters.param-name` (for named parameters) or `steps.step-name.outputs.result` (for the stdout of a `script` or `container` template).

Example ([see full Workflow](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/output-parameter.yaml)):

```yaml
  - name: output-parameter
    steps:
    - - name: generate-parameter
        template: whalesay
    - - name: consume-parameter
        template: print-message
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: message
            value: "{{steps.generate-parameter.outputs.parameters.hello-param}}"
```

**Within a `dag` template**, you may access the output of various tasks using a similar syntax, just using `tasks.` instead of `steps.`.

Example ([see full Workflow](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/dag-conditional-parameters.yaml)):

```yaml
    - name: main
      dag:
        tasks:
          - name: flip-coin
            template: flip-coin
          - name: heads
            depends: flip-coin
            template: heads
            when: "{{tasks.flip-coin.outputs.result}} == heads"
          - name: tails
            depends: flip-coin
            template: tails
            when: "{{tasks.flip-coin.outputs.result}} == tails"
```

**Within a `container` or `script` template**, you may access *only the inputs of that template**. You may not directly access the outputs of steps or tasks from steps or tasks templates from a container or script template.

## Referencing a step output from a DAG

As mentioned above, a DAG template cannot directly reference step outputs from a `steps` template. But a step within a `steps` template can *pass a step output to a DAG template*.

In your example, it would look something like this:

```yaml
  templates:
  - name: the-entrypoint
    steps:
    - - name: step01
        template: first-step
    - - name: step02
        template: second-step
    - - name: step03
        template: third-step
    - - name: step04-the-dag-step
        template: fourth-step
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: some-param
            value: "{{steps.step03.outputs.result}}"
  - name: fourth-step
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: some-param
    dag:
      tasks:
        # use the input parameter in the fourth-step template with "{{inputs.parameters.some-param}}"
```

## tl;dr

`steps.` and `tasks.` variables are meant to be *referenced within a single steps- or tasks-template*, but they can be explicitly *passed between templates*. If you need to use the output of a step in a DAG, directly pass that output as an argument where the DAG is invoked.

In your case, the DAG template is invoked as the last of four steps, so that is where you will pass the argument.

<sub>* Okay, you also have access to [various other variables](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/variables.md) from within a `script` or `container` template, but you don't have access to variables that are scoped as internal variables within another template.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, @michael-crenshaw! What you said was what I ended up doing. I did not type that up and suggest as a solution because I thought there may have been some syntax that allows one to access variables across different templates. Even if there is not, I am glad I did not do it since you explained it a lot better than I ever would! Thank you!